# CSS Grid Full Screen Scrolling Content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a full screen layout with a scrolling content section.

Problem is the content section will not scroll, but instead the whole page scrolls.

```css
.view-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 75px auto 50px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header-container {}

.body-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
}

.sidebar-container {}

.content-container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.footer-container {}
```

```html
<div className="view-container">
  <div className="header-container">Header</div>
  <div className="body-container">
    <div className="sidebar-container">Side Bar</div>
    <div className="content-container">
      Scrolling Content
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> More Content...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="footer-container">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.view-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 75px auto 50px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header-container {}

.body-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
}

.sidebar-container {}

.content-container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.footer-container {}
```

```html
<div class="view-container">
  <div class="header-container">Header</div>
  <div class="body-container">
    <div class="sidebar-container">Side Bar</div>
    <div class="content-container">
      Scrolling Content
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> More Content...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-container">Footer</div>
</div>
```

You need to specify height to get scroll worked otherwise it will take height auto.

Comment: How do I get the `height` of the content container to fill the layout? If I put 100% for height I get scroll bars on the main view